# C# Selenium No new Window Handles When Opening A New Tab In Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

Selenium for Chrome and Firefox, coding in C#, will not handle switching over to the new tab that is opening during my automation test. I don't think it focuses on the new tab open because when I run my program completely, I receive this error:  "out of range" exception and "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

I've tried using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

and

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]).Close(); // close the first tab
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait 5 seconds just in case
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]); //Makes sure I'm on the correct tab
```

but there is no luck. If I don't close the first tab, I receive the error: "NoSuchElementException:Unable to locate element:{method...}" which I assume is correct because the focus is still on the first tab. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Once you've closed `tab[0]`, doesn't the old `tab[1]` become the new `tab[0]`?

Comment: Yes it does, I did not notice that. Thanks. But now my only problem is that the xpath I have as my input is unable to locate on the new tab. That's another issue I will find out. Thanks again

Comment: If that's solved the problem your question mentions I can post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: One more question, does the window automatically goes into focus when the driver is switched to it? Because as of now, either my window isn't focused or my xpath is wrong because I'm always getting an "Unable to locate Element" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've closed `tab[0]`, the old `tab[1]` becomes the new `tab[0]`, so you should be switching to `tab[0]`.

Selenium operates in the background so the window does not need to be in focus while it is running. This also means that Selenium will never change the focus back to the browser window. If you are watching the window while your code runs however you should be able to see the browser changing tabs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've worded my question better. What I meant to ask, does the new tab/window change focus from the old tab/window when the driver switches to it using the driver.switchTo function above?

Comment: Yes it does, that's what the function is for ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think my XPath is incorrect then. Thank you so much for your time helping me and answer :)

Comment: To test XPaths you could use Chrome's Dev Tools, they allow you to search your DOM by XPath when you're on your page. http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/ Keep in mind that opening the Dev Tools detaches Selenium though.